# Overriding or Creating Custom Pages for record detail of specific objects

Tags: community, redirect, community-builder

I am using the Napili Salesforce Community Template and I want to modify just the record detail page for a specific custom object. Is that possible? I see how I can go into `Community Builder > Page Editor > Record Detail` and edit all record detail pages but I don't see how I can edit it only for specific objects such as a `myObject__c` custom object. Or, alternatively is there a way to re-direct it in the community when it does to that specific page?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to modify just the record detail page for a specific custom object, but you'll need to create that page first.

When you are in `Community Builder`, go to `Page Manager > + > Create Object Page > [Choose your Object] > Create`. Check the screenshot for the first 3 steps.

[image]

Now you can go back to `Community Builder > Page Editor > OBJECT_NAME Detail` and edit the record detail page layout for only this specific object.

Answer (score 0):

This article should get you your answer - [View and Create Record Detail Pages in Napili - releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_networks_create_record_detail_view.htm)

Also, in case you need to customize the record detail further - like to move the field around in the detail layout - create a new page layout in Salesforce for your object and assign it to the profiles which have community access. This new layout will be used when displaying the record detail page.